# How to make qtcreator work with c++11

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++11

I am trying to make school project works locally, but I keep having trouble with qtcreator and c++11.

The compilator keeps saying it can't use c++11 stuffs:

```
/Users/yoong93/Qt5.6.2/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:
757: error: no type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'
    inline std::u16string toStdU16String() const;

       ~~~~~^
```

While the `.pro` file have following lines:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
CONFIG += c++14
unix:!macx {
    LIBS += -lGLU
}
macx {
    QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_X86_64 = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64
    CONFIG +=c++11
}
```

So I expect there is nothing wrong with the project file, which is the most common issue that others had. I have no clue where I went wrong. Does anyone know about the issue?

I am using OSX El Captain version 10.11.6, and Qt 5.6.1, and I have Xcode version 7.3.1 installed.

Comment: My Mac has XCode 8 and Qt 5.7 with no issues. If upgrading doesn't fix it for you, try showing the compiler output that is generated so we can see what parameters are being passed to gcc/clang from Qt Creator.

Comment: have you tried this `.pro` file with only the two first lines?

Answer (score 0):

The following `qmake` compiler flags worked for me on `OSX El Captain`:

```
CONFIG += c++14
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-c++11-extensions
```